# Posting a form to a php file that will process it and show echoes to facebox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebox

Need some help here. I have a form that will be fetched to another php file that is on its "action" attribute and must display the echoes in that php file. But, when I submit it. It only shows a blank facebox pop up. I think theres a little problem within the jquery. Anyone who can fix this? Thanks :)

heres my form:

```
<form action="Examinersubmit.php" name="asign" id="asign" method="POST">
<input id ="adfirstname"  name="adfirstname"  type="text" onkeyup="isalpha(this)" class="input_field"  maxlength="60" />
<input id="adlastname" name="adlastname" type="text" onkeyup="isalpha(this)" class="input_field"  maxlength="60" />
<input type="submit" id="AdReg" name="AdReg" class="submit_btn float_l" value="Register" />
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="level" />
<input  type="text" class="input_field" id="sec1" name="sec1" />
<input type="reset" name="Submit4" class="submit_btn float_l" value="Clear All" />
<input  type="text" class="input_field" id="sec2" name="sec2" />
<input  type="text" class="input_field" id="sec3" name="sec3" />
</form>
```

heres the jquery script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({

        loadingImage : 'src/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'src/closelabel.png'

      });
       $("#asign").submit(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('action');
    $("<a>").attr('href',href).facebox().click();
    return false;
    });
    });
  </script>
```

The codes on the examinersubmit.php is working fine when it is "not" on facebox.

Comment: I really have no idea on ajax. how can i use it there?

Answer (score 0):

you are returning `false` in the submit callback, your php script is never submitted to. Just providing the action url to `facebox` will not submit the form and show the results in it. If you are wanting to get the output of the script you need to use ajax

```
$("#asign").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var href = $(this).attr('action');
   $.ajax({
      url:href,
      type:"POST",
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      dataType:"html",
      success:function(data){
         //data holds the html returned by the php script
         //do whatever you need to put the html into facebox.
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: did you put the code to put the html held in `data` into a `facebox` within the success function callback (where the comments are)?

Comment: Im using $_POSTS . do I need to do like this? examinersubmit.php?firstname='Adfirstname' blah blah like that in javascript?

Comment: copy and use the code in the answer, it uses ajax to submit your form to the php script, replace the comments with code that will show the html in facebox, again the html that is generated from the post will be in the `data` variable. I am not familiar with facebox so you will have to look up their documentation on how to add html.